# jQuery isn't doing anything inside of CasperJS' evaluate() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using the CasperJS for extracting some content from HTML data. For that I put some jQuery code in the `evaluate()` function, but the jQuery code is not working there. I don't know how to use it properly.

I'm using the following code, sample:

```
var resultObj  =  [];

var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
       loadImages: false,
       loadPlugins: false,
       userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1588.0 Safari/537.36'
    },
});

casper.start();

//another codes

casper.traverseHtml =   function(){
    var executer    =   casper.evaluate(function(){
        var htmlText    =   '<div><div class="tp">x</div><div class="tp">y</div><div class="tp">z</div><div class="tp">p</div></div>';
        object = $('<div/>').html(htmlText).contents();         
        object.find('.tp').each(function(index, element) {
            resultObj.push({value:index});
        });  
        return resultObj;

    });
    resultObj   =   executer;
}
casper.then(function() {
    casper.traverseHtml();
});

//codes

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(resultObj)).exit();
});
```

I got a `null` result for this code, but when I'm replacing the `traverseHtml` function as,

```
casper.traverseHtml =   function(){
    var executer    =   casper.evaluate(function(){            
        return [{value:"1234"}];
    });
    resultObj   =   executer;
}
```

Then it is giving output as,

```
[{"value":"1234"}]
```

I don't know how to correct this.

Comment: Does the remote page have jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

First try passing the jQuery variable into the evaluate function - possibly a quick fix:

```
var executer    =   casper.evaluate(function($){
```

Second, verify the remote page has jQuery and check the version.  If jQuery isn't present, inject (docs found [here](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-jquery-with-casperjs)):

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["includes/jquery.min.js"]
});
```

If using an older version of jQuery, you may need to replace '$' with 'jQuery' in body of function. Try this:

```
var executer    =   casper.evaluate(function($){
    var htmlText    =   '<div><div class="tp">x</div><div class="tp">y</div><div class="tp">z</div><div class="tp">p</div></div>';
    object = jQuery('<div/>').html(htmlText).contents();         
    object.find('.tp').each(function(index, element) {
        resultObj.push({value:index});
    });  
    return resultObj;
});
```

If those options do not work, open Google Chrome browser and test your jQuery code in the console on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS has two contexts and since CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS it has the same two contexts. You get access to the page/DOM context through [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate), but it is sandboxed. It means that you cannot access any variable that is defined outside of the callback function for `casper.evaluate()`. Everything that you want to use inside has to be explicitly passed in. See the PhantomJS [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) for more information.

The problem is that you didn't define `resultObj` in the page context so you cannot `push` anything onto an `undefined` reference.

```
var executer = casper.evaluate(function(){
    var resultObj = []; // only additional line

    var htmlText = '<div><div class="tp">x</div><div class="tp">y</div><div class="tp">z</div><div class="tp">p</div></div>';
    var obj = $('<div/>').html(htmlText).contents();         
    obj.find('.tp').each(function(index, element) {
        resultObj.push({value:index});
    });  
    return resultObj;
});
```

I also changed `object` to a local variable `obj`.

If the page does not provide jQuery, you need to include it yourself:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["jquery.min.js"]
});
```

Provided you put `jquery.min.js` in your run directory.

---

If you want to see the actual error which is hidden in the page context, you can listen to the ["page.error" event](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error):

```
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});
```

There are more interesting events: [Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js).